# Typedef function pointer error

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to compile some legacy C++ project and ran into an error, and I can't figure out what's going on.

The error is in this line (18):

```
 typedef uint16_t (*vfunc)();
```

GCC output:

```
vflow.h:18: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'uint16_t' with no type
vflow.h:18: error: typedef 'uint16_t' is initialized (use decltype instead)
vflow.h:18: error: 'vfunc' was not declared in this scope
```

My C++ is even worse than my English; please help. =)

Comment: Have you included `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>` beforehand so you have `uint16_t` defined?  It looks like you don't yet have `uint16_t` defined.

Comment: Yes! That's it, thank you. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transferring my comment to an answer:

> Have you included either `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>` beforehand so you have `uint16_t` defined? It looks like you don't yet have `uint16_t` defined.

Judging from the response, this is your problem.